# Hibernate retrieving only NULL values

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two microservices that access my MySQL database using Spring Data/Hibernate, one of the microservices works perfectly with the DB, but the other doesn't map the values properly to the fields and the fields remain NULL.

Do you have any idea what might be the cause of this? I am using the exact same classes with same mapping for each of the Entities (basically copied them over).

Thank you in advance, I will provide more info if needed, I just need a direction since I have been stuck on this for quite a while now.

Comment: do you have any of your Id columns null for those records ?

Comment: @SKumar nope, only have 2 records and both have their IDs set to numbers

Comment: Is this random behaviour, means one of them stop working with db or just a specific one?

Comment: @code_mechanic from the get go, only the one application that created the initial db fetches the values properly, the other gets only the id, rest of the columns are null, even though in the db they have values. Also something I noticed is, that if I write it in pure JDBC then I am able to fetch the results properly, but then I am doing the mapping by hand, so I think that has something to do with it.

Comment: Please post some code and configuration in both service (minimum possible), any difference in setup any how?